# unable to display response from post request in react

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react development.
I am able to get response from post request and print in console but nt sure how to display it on main page.

code from app.js for my ui

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Enter Email Address to Verify</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.response.body}</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p>
            <strong>Address:</strong>
          </p>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ post: e.target.value })}
          />
          <button type="submit">check</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

this is the way i get it print on console

console.log(wellFormed, validDomain, validMailbox);

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/api/v1/verifier', {
      method: 'POST',
     // body: this.state,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),

    });
    const body = await response.text();
    this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
  };
```

From verifier method

```
res.send(

    `response received , welllformed = ${wellFormed}, validDomain = ${validDomain}, validMailbox = ${validMailbox}`,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you will get a JSON response which is nothing but an Array of objects. So you can put that to a state then use higher order function `map` to render each element to the Dom.

let's assume that your response is like this.

```
[{"activeCases":"5132472","country":"USA"} ,"activeCases":"455602","country":"India"}]
```

you can refer each object as course(it can be any name) inside the map method.

```
{this.state.response.map((course) => (
         <div>
             <h3>Active cases :{course.activeCases}</h3>
             <h5>country :{course.country}</h6>
         </div>
 ))}
```

This will render each data in your repose to the Dom like thise.

```
Active cases :5132472
country :USA
Active cases :455602
country :India
```

Comment: pls check my updated answer, as m nt clear what u wan explain

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Enter Email Address to Verify</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.response.body}</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p>
            <strong>Email Address:</strong>
          </p>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ post: e.target.value })}
          />
          <button type="submit">Verify</button>
        </form>
        <p>{this.state.responseToPost}</p>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

This worked for me